# Uploading to FTP slow

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, webclient

following code is extremely slow compared to filezilla (code uploads at about 100 kbps, filezilla at 28 Mbps)

```
    Private Sub UploadFTP(ByVal Datei As String, ByVal Dateiname As String, ByVal Ftp As String, ByVal Benutzername As String, ByVal Passwort As String)
    Try


    ' WebClient
    ftpUpload = New Net.WebClient

    ' URL mit Zieldatei
    Dim url As String = Ftp & IIf(Ftp.EndsWith("/"), "", "/") & Dateiname

    ' Anmeldedaten am FTP-Server
    ftpUpload.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(Benutzername, Passwort)


    ' Datei asnychron uploaden
        ftpUpload.UploadFileAsync(New Uri(url), Datei)

    Catch ex As Exception

        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & ex.ToString & vbNewLine
    End Try
End Sub
```

after a few hours of googeling i was not able to find anything pointing me to the right direction. why is the upload so slow and how can i increase it?

EDIT

i think it is a buffer problem. but didnt find a way to increase the buffer.

thanks

Comment: Can you profile this code to see what's taking the time? How about CPU or memory usage?

Comment: Try using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfkdh7eb(v=vs.90).aspx Don't know inner workings of either of these methods and don't know which one is faster, just giving you something to try...

Comment: hello guys! thanks for your answers. i am quite confident that it is a buffer problem. the buffer is small, whilst filezilla has a buffer of 256 kb... but i dont know how to increase the buffer and searches didnt help either..